# Adding even values to new list Python

Tags: python, list

If I have a list and I want to create a list with only even values of the original list, how would I do that?

I originally have:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
for v in list1:
    if v % 2 == 0:
        list2 += v
print list2
```

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well the answer to *your* questions are: "No", "no", and "don't know because it doesn't run" (`list2 += v` will break). He just wanted some code that works, and now that he has it, let's give him a chance to see if it's good enough for his needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehension is the way to go:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i%2 == 0]
print list2 # => [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extend an existing `list2` (not necessarily initially empty):

```
list2.extend(v for v in list1 if v % 2 == 0)
```

If there's no "initial value" for `list2`, and you just want to build it from scratch:

```
list2 = [v for v in list1 if v % 2 == 0]
```

You'll notice that the inner part is identical -- you can use that part in different ways (inside brackets to create a new list, as argument to `.extend` to extend an existing list, and so forth).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if not i%2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be the most readable solution:

```
list2 = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0: list1)
```

or if you have to use this function multiple times:

```
is_even = lambda x: x % 2 == 0

list2 = filter(is_even, list1)
```